# Google redirects me to local version every time

Tags: google-chrome, redirection

I'm in Germany atm and every time I go to google.com they redirect me to google.de. Even if I call google.com/ncr they just redirect me to google.de again! I even tried google.com/?hl=en, which sets the site itself to English, but still gives me German search results. At this point I'm so annoyed I'm actually considering to just use bing. **How can I use google.com?**

(I use Chrome as browser, if that helps. Also I noticed right after installing the browser google.com/ncr worked just fine, but as soon as I bookmarked it it stopped working for whatever reason. Now it doesn't even work anymore when I type it in manually.)

Comment: What happens in "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "N" ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/398790/how-can-i-force-my-browser-to-search-google-in-english, http://superuser.com/questions/306171/how-do-i-revert-chromes-google-search-to-english-after-experimenting-with-the-n, http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66455/how-to-force-google-to-not-mind-my-location-during-search, http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66835/how-to-force-google-search-to-only-return-english-results

Comment: Have you tried `ping google.com` and used the IP address in your browser? In the UK it is not obvious where the results are coming from, but they are different from what `google.co.uk` returns. Oddly, the IP from `google.co.uk` is different, but the same as from `google.de`, and the search results seem to be the same as from `google.com`'s IP, and there are no ads! If this doesn't give you `google.com` results, try a US-based proxy.

Comment: I've just discovered that `https://www.google.com` doesn't show redirection, though it does give UK-based ads and some UK location-based search results. I'm more confused than ever...